# Composing an Apollo App

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I've been experimenting with GraphQL/Apollo in Typescript and run into a huge amount of really obvious typing issues that make me wonder whether I'm just doing it wrong.

Effectively, what I'd like to do (since it makes sense to me) is compose the data for my components by plastering in multiple HOC calls.  Here's an example of what I mean (sans imports)

```
interface Props {
  theme: Theme;
}

class Navigation extends React.Component<Props & ViewerProps & PageProps> {
  render() {
    const { viewer, page } = this.props;
    return <h1>Hello, {viewer.name}; welcome to {page.name}</h1>;
  }
}

export default withPage(withViewer(Navigation));
```

Elsewhere:

```
<Navigation theme={this.theme} />
```

Is this actually a pattern of any kind in Apollo?  Are there any references out there which use this, or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Apollo 2.1 they upgraded to use render prop functions.

https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html which will help with stronger typing through the components.

https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/introducing-react-apollo-2-1-c837cc23d926

One thing I've been doing with components with HoCs is to cast the HoC with **React.ComponentType** so that it can make sure you're passing in the correct props to the component

```
const NavigationContainer: React.ComponentType<Props> = 
  withPage(withViewer(Navigation));
export default NavigationContainer;
```